# Should this be a different data type?

Tags: c#, datetime, dictionary, text-files, streamreader

I am writing a program where someone can add, mark as complete and add homework. The program stores all information in a dictionary and puts it all into a text file so the data is not lost. However on line 101 i am getting this error "System.ArgumentNullException: 'String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s'". Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong?

I've tried changing the data types of some things but still nothing, and all the data is written and read from the text file in the same order: Description, subject, teacher, date due, status. SO i have no clue what's going wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace HomeworkTingaling
{
    class Program
    {
        struct homeworkStruct
        {
            public string subject;
            public string teacher;
            public DateTime dateDue;
            public bool completed;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> homework = new Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct>();
            int selection = 0;
            bool YorN = true;
            selection = menu(selection);
            //gets a selection from the menu method then decides which methods to use depending on the users input
            while (YorN == true)
            {
                if (selection == 1)
                {
                    //get the homework, display it and then display the menu
                    homework = getHomework(homework);
                    displayHomework(homework);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    dictToTxt(homework);
                    menu(selection);                   
                }
                if(selection == 2)
                {
                    homework = getHomework(homework);
                    completeHomework(homework);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    dictToTxt(homework);
                    menu(selection);
                }
                if(selection == 3)
                {
                    homework = getHomework(homework);
                    addHomework(homework);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    dictToTxt(homework);
                    menu(selection);
                }
                if (selection == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodybe!");
                    YorN = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //menu method
        static int menu(int selection)
        {
            selection = 0;
            bool YorN = true;
            //loop continues until a valid number is entered, at which point it breaks the loop and passes the input to the main 
            while (YorN == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number that corresponds with what you would like to do: ");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------\n1. View homework\n2. Complete Homework\n3. Add Homework\n4. Exit\n----------------------------------------");
                selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (selection < 1 || selection > 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number selection!");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                else
                {
                    YorN = false;
                }
            }
            return selection;
        }

        //getHomework method
        static Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> getHomework(Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> homework)
        {
            //FILE NOT OPENING
            StreamReader homeworkReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\HomeworkTIngaling\HomeworkTIngaling\bin\Debug\homework.txt", true);
            while (!homeworkReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //convert to the correct datatypes in the order or the txt file, then add to homework array
                string name = homeworkReader.ReadLine();
                homeworkStruct thishomework;

                thishomework.subject = homeworkReader.ReadLine();
                thishomework.teacher = homeworkReader.ReadLine();
                thishomework.dateDue = DateTime.Parse(homeworkReader.ReadLine());
                thishomework.completed = bool.Parse(homeworkReader.ReadLine());
                homework.Add(name, thishomework);               
            }
            homeworkReader.Close();
            return homework;
        }

        //display homework
        static void displayHomework(Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> homework)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, homeworkStruct> item in homework)
            {
                if (item.Value.completed == false)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Homework: {1}  Subject: {2}  Teacher: {3}  Due Date: {4}  Status: {5}", item.Key, item.Value.subject, item.Value.teacher, item.Value.dateDue, item.Value.completed);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Homework: {1}  Subject: {2}  Teacher: {3}  Due Date: {4}  Status: {5}", item.Key, item.Value.subject, item.Value.teacher, item.Value.dateDue, item.Value.completed);
                }
            }
        }

        //turning dictionary to text file
        static Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> dictToTxt(Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> homework)
        {            
            StreamWriter dictToText = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\HomeworkTIngaling\HomeworkTIngaling\bin\Debug\homework.txt", true);
            //adds each item into the homework dictionary
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, homeworkStruct> item in homework)
            {
                dictToText.WriteLine(item.Key);
                dictToText.WriteLine(item.Value.subject);
                dictToText.WriteLine(item.Value.teacher);
                dictToText.WriteLine(item.Value.dateDue);
                dictToText.WriteLine(item.Value.completed);
                dictToText.WriteLine("");
            }
            dictToText.Close();
            return homework;
        }

        //mark homework as completed
        static Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> completeHomework(Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> homework)
        {
            bool YorN = true;
            //displaying the homework so they can look at the description of the homework which they would like to mark as complete
            displayHomework(homework);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the homework you would like to mark as complete: ");
            string selection;
            //look through the dictionary until the correct homework is found, if not found, run again
            while (YorN == true)
            {
                selection = Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, homeworkStruct> item in homework)
                {
                    if (item.Key == selection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The homework", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow, "{0} has been marked as complete!", item.Key);
                        if (item.Value.completed == true)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //CHANGE BOOL 'COMPLETED' TO TRUE
                        }
                        YorN = false;
                    }                    
                }
                if (YorN == true)
                {           
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid homework description: ");                    
                }
            }
            return homework;
        }
        //addHomework method
        static Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> addHomework(Dictionary<string, homeworkStruct> homework)
        {
            bool YorN = true;
            //getting input from user (entering all individual details)
            Console.WriteLine("Describe the homework: ");
            string description = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What subject is this for? ");
            string subject = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is the name of the teacher? ");
            string teacher = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What date is this homework due in for? ");
            DateTime dateDue = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Is this homework completed? (Please enter a 'y' for yes or a 'n' for no)");
            string status;
            bool complete = true;
            //only continue when the question is answered
            while (YorN == true)
            {
                status = Console.ReadLine();
                if (status == "y")
                {
                    complete = true;
                    YorN = false;
                }
                if (status == "n")
                {
                    complete = false;
                    YorN = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter either a 'y' or 'n': ");
                }
            }
            //ready all info for entering into the homework dictionary
            string newHomeworkStrin = description;
            homeworkStruct newHomework;
            newHomework.subject = subject;
            newHomework.teacher = teacher;
            newHomework.dateDue = dateDue;
            newHomework.completed = complete;
            //add all details to homeworks dictionary
            homework.Add(newHomeworkStrin, newHomework);
            //pass back the homework array
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, your homework has been added!");
            return homework;
        }
    }
}
```

It lets me add info and that part works. This is the data currently stored in the file (each bit of data is on a new line):
"Maths Study Pack 6"
"Maths"
"Mr.Math"
"07/01/2020 00:00:00"
"True"

This should then be displayed in green on the screen but line 101 keeps pulling up an error.

Comment: This happens because `StreamReader.ReadLine()` returns `null` when the end of the stream is reached. You are then passing this `null` value to `DateTime.Parse()` which throws the exception as it doesn't allow `null` as a parameter.

Comment: Not sure what line 109 is, however, if you use `Console.WriteLine` with placeholders, placeholder numbers starts with `0` rather than `1`. Thus, you should first have `{0}` followed by `{1}` and end on `{4}`.

Comment: @BionicCode how do i resolve that?

Comment: You can use `StreamReader.EndOfStream` or `StreamReader.Peek()` to check if the stream has reached its end. Or use `DateTime.TryParse()` which allows `null` as a parameter but would return `false` in case the parameter is `null`

Comment: @BionicCode I'm sorry, I'm quite new but would you be able to show an example of how I'd use those first 2 commands in this code? It's dine if not, I'll try and figure it out myself :)

Comment: I added and updated an answer to show safe stream access and safe parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `StreamReader.ReadLine()` returns `null` when the end of the stream is reached. You are then passing this `null` value to `DateTime.Parse()` which throws the exception as it doesn't allow `null` as a parameter.

You can use `StreamReader.EndOfStream` or `StreamReader.Peek()` to check if the stream has reached its end. Or use `DateTime.TryParse()` which allows `null` as a parameter but would return false in case the parameter is `null`:

```
using (StreamReader homeworkReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\HomeworkTIngaling\HomeworkTIngaling\bin\Debug\homework.txt", true))
{
  while (!homeworkReader.EndOfStream)
  {
    string name = homeworkReader.ReadLine();
    homeworkStruct thishomework;

    thishomework.subject = homeworkReader.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    thishomework.teacher = homeworkReader.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    thishomework.dateDue = DateTime.TryParse(homeworkReader.ReadLine(), out DateTime dueDate) 
      ? dueDate
      : DateTime.Now;

    thishomework.completed = bool.TryParse(homeworkReader.ReadLine(), out bool isCompleted)
      ? isCompleted
      : false;        

    if (!homework.Contains(name))
    {
      homework.Add(name, thishomework);    
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing that, however now the program doesn't always have a value for the datedue, therefore thishomewowrk" isn't always assigned and cannot be added to homework. What do i do about that?

Comment: You either have a malformed file which is missing the date or you need to provide a default `DateTime` as a fallback value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: In case the date (or any other data) is missing you can consider to ignore the data set as it is incomplete and therefore can be evaluated as invalid. You can ignore this record.

Comment: The program still kicks up a fuss on the "homework.add(name, thishomework)" line as not all values are necessarily always assigned

Comment: Yes, so you decided to keep homework although their data is incomplete? Then do as I said before: assign default values in case of missing data. I'll show you.

Comment: Also because a `Dictionary` doesn't allow duplicate keys you should check for its presence before adding it. In case you have duplicate `name` values you will get an exception too.

Comment: It now works, however everything comes in a very wrong order. It ignored the first line and entered 2 items wrong

Comment: It wasn't like this before? You mean the first line from the file? And what is wrong with the two items?

Comment: says "TryAdd" isn't  a thing

Comment: Ok, `TryAdd` is a different .NET version. Must use `Dictionary.Contains()` instead.

Comment: never mind, it works, was just me being a bit stupid. Thank you very much!